# first name and title without parenthesis in a single regex

Tags: regex

how to put the following 2 regex together to capture both groups in one expression:

`(^[a-zA-Z]*)` should capture the first name, [first_here](https://regex101.com/r/e1JxZI/1/)

`\((.+?)\)` should capture the title

to extract:

```
Donald President
Mike Vice President
```

from:

```
Donald Trump (President)
Mike Pence (Vice President)
```

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z]*).*\([^)]+)\)`

Comment: @Adam Smith it has unmatched parenthesis but i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^(?P<name>\w+)[^()]+\((?P<function>[^()]+)\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lXLuRP/1/).

---

Obviously this will work for

```
Cake Cookie (Sugar)
```

as well. If you want to limit it to names only, use a database.

Comment: What if function has double parenthesis such as in `Dawn Robin (Global Director (People))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine as follows to match first name and title. then use first and second captured group to form output.

```regex
^([a-zA-Z]*).*?\(([^)]+?)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e1JxZI/2)